# Bar Chart how to set xAxis entries in BOTTOM and radial position

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

With my code the x values are positioned horizontally below my graph but I want also they are in an oblique position (or radial) and not horizontal.

```
        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rotate the labels of the `XAxis` like this:

```
xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(90f);
```

You can find more information on this method in the [`XAxis`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.0-beta1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/XAxis.html) documentation:

> [`setLabelRotationAngle(float angle)`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.0-beta1/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/XAxis.html#setLabelRotationAngle-float-): Sets the angle for drawing the X axis labels (in degrees).

Comment: Hello @TR4Android, how can I set a value for exemple the position 3 ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean with "set a value the position 3", can you clarify what you want to do with an example, please? Thanks.

Comment: I want to to put on X entries, the specifical date locating in my array list mDateList. I have tried to use following code but it is the same which appear on buttom: public DayAxisValueFormatter(BarLineChartBase<?> chart, ArrayList<Long> DateList, int size) {
    this.chart = chart;
    this.mDateList = DateList;
    this.mSize = size;
}
@Override
public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
    return longToStringForTimeReal(mDateList.get( mSize));
}

And I call it like this:
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new DayAxisValueFormatter(mChart,mDateList, mDateList.size()));